# How do I add textbox lines to separate ListView columns?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, textbox

[image]

I have googled around but haven't found any examples of how to do this? I am trying to add textbox lines to a Listview, e.g. line 1 > column 1, line 2 > column 2, line 3 > column 3, etc. If anyone can give an example of how to achieve this I would be very grateful (VB.NET, C..., LINQ).

**What I have tried**

I have tried using the following code adapted from different sources but it is adding all the textbox lines to each column as per the image above:

**The Code**

```
For Each strLine In TextBox42.Lines
        strLine.Split(vbNewLine)

        ListView5.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {strLine, strLine, strLine, strLine, strLine, strLine, strLine, Today.Date}))

    Next
```

**What I need**

[image]

Each time a button is pressed I need to enter a different word with its classification from textbox lines as a ListView item/row as per the image (compare the two images). The hyphens
indicate that there has been no data input for that column but this can change as the user adds information about each word/lexeme.

**Other Code I have Tried**

```
ListView5.Items.AddRange(Array.ConvertAll(Enumerable.Range(0, TextBox42.Lines.Length).ToArray, Function(x) New ListViewItem(New String() {TextBox42.Lines(x)})))
```

Comment: Something like `ListView5.Items.AddRange(TextBox42.Lines.Select(Function(line) New ListViewItem(line)).Append(New ListViewItem(Today.Date.ToString())).ToArray())`. This `strLine.Split(vbNewLine)` is wrong. The [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Split)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) method doesn't convert a string to string array, it **returns** a string array.

Comment: If you are showing a grid, wouldn't `DataGridView` be a better control to use?

Comment: I found some old demo code of mine, pasted in the answer below. The secret sauce seems to be to use the `ListViewItem.SubItems` collection to add your properties

Comment: I think using [DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) should meet your needs, an easy-to-use control that displays data in tabular form.

Comment: @dr.null thanks for your code example. I just tried using it and it works but it adds all the textbox lines to the first column? How do I add line 1 > column 1, line 2 > column 2, line 3 > column 3 and keep going until all the textbox lines have been added? I currently have 8 columns in the LVW but this needs to be flexible because in the future I want to allow the user to add other columns.

Comment: ah right. It's just `ListView5.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(TextBox42.Lines.Append(Now.ToString()).ToArray()))`. Format the appended date as needed.

Comment: Hey thanks dr.null. That works great! The date is being placed in the wrong column because it should go in the last column. I don't know if there's a way to do that with the code you supplied. I removed the date from your code and am looking for a way to insert the date in the last column using a separate line of code. But if there's a way to include this in your code it would help me a lot to learn more!

Comment: Either add empty lines in the text box to have lines count = columns count - 1 in order to use that one-liner, or just add the date to the last column in a separate line. Keep it simple. You could instead use a `List(Of String)` to collect the values including the empty lines and date then pass it to the `ListViewItem` ctor as string array by calling the `.ToArray()` ex-method. `Dim lst = new List(Of String)`, `lst.Add(..)` or `lst.AddRange(...)` to add items, and lastly `ListView5.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(lst.ToArray()))`. You could use `-` instead of the empty lines.

Comment: Thanks once again dr.null!  I think if I follow your suggestion I can just use your code as is with the date included! Can you add your comment(s) as an answer so that I can mark them as the answer? One question, what is ListViewItem ctor...?

Comment: ctor = constructor. Feel free to post that as answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider `DataGridView` for your solution. However, I did find some old demo code of mine...

[image: Detail view]

[image: Icon view]

```
Public Class Form1

  Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    'ListView is a Windows Explorer style view - user can switch between icons and details
    lvwFiles.Columns.Clear()
    lvwFiles.Columns.Add("Filename", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lvwFiles.Columns.Add("Date modified", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lvwFiles.Columns.Add("Type", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lvwFiles.Columns.Add("Size", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

    Dim iml As New ImageList()
    iml.Images.Add("AAA", GetImage("AAA"))
    iml.Images.Add("BBB", GetImage("BBB"))
    iml.Images.Add("CCC", GetImage("CCC"))
    iml.Images.Add("DDD", GetImage("DDD"))
    iml.ImageSize = New Size(64, 64)
    lvwFiles.LargeImageList = iml
    lvwFiles.Items.Add("AAA.txt", "AAA").SubItems.AddRange({New Date(2017, 6, 2), "Text File", 20000})
    lvwFiles.Items.Add("BBB.txt", "BBB").SubItems.AddRange({New Date(2017, 5, 3), "Text File", 10000})
    lvwFiles.Items.Add("CCC.exe", "CCC").SubItems.AddRange({New Date(2017, 4, 4), "Application", 40000})
    lvwFiles.Items.Add("DDD.txt", "DDD").SubItems.AddRange({New Date(2017, 3, 5), "Text File", 30000})
  End Sub

  Private Sub radDetails_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radDetails.CheckedChanged
    If radDetails.Checked Then
      lvwFiles.View = View.Details
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub radIcons_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radIcons.CheckedChanged
    If radIcons.Checked Then
      lvwFiles.View = View.LargeIcon
    End If
  End Sub

  Function GetImage(s As String) As Image
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(64, 64)
    Using gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
      gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64))
      gfx.DrawString(s, New Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12), Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0)
    End Using
    Return bmp
  End Function


  Private Sub lvwFiles_ColumnClick(sender As Object, e As ColumnClickEventArgs) Handles lvwFiles.ColumnClick
    Static sintLastColumnClicked As Integer = -1
    If sintLastColumnClicked = e.Column Then
      Me.lvwFiles.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer(e.Column, ListViewItemComparer.SortOrder_ENUM.Descending)
      sintLastColumnClicked = -1
    Else
      Me.lvwFiles.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer(e.Column, ListViewItemComparer.SortOrder_ENUM.Ascending)
      sintLastColumnClicked = e.Column
    End If
    ' Call the sort method to manually sort.
    lvwFiles.Sort()
  End Sub

  Class ListViewItemComparer
    Implements IComparer
    Enum SortOrder_ENUM As Integer
      Ascending = 1
      Descending = -1
    End Enum
    Private mintColumn As Integer
    Private mintSortOrder As Integer
    Sub New(column As Integer, sortOrder As SortOrder_ENUM)
      mintColumn = column
      If sortOrder = SortOrder_ENUM.Ascending Then
        mintSortOrder = 1
      Else
        mintSortOrder = -1
      End If
    End Sub
    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
      Dim returnVal As Integer = -1
      Dim lviX As ListViewItem = DirectCast(x, ListViewItem)
      Dim lviY As ListViewItem = DirectCast(y, ListViewItem)
      Select Case mintColumn
        Case 0, 2 'text sort
          returnVal = [String].Compare(lviX.SubItems(mintColumn).Text, lviY.SubItems(mintColumn).Text)
        Case 1 'date sort
          returnVal = Date.Compare(CDate(lviX.SubItems(mintColumn).Text), CDate(lviY.SubItems(mintColumn).Text))
        Case 3 'integer sort
          If CInt(lviX.SubItems(mintColumn).Text) < CInt(lviY.SubItems(mintColumn).Text) Then
            returnVal = -1
          ElseIf CInt(lviX.SubItems(mintColumn).Text) = CInt(lviY.SubItems(mintColumn).Text) Then
            returnVal = 0
          Else
            returnVal = 1
          End If
      End Select

      Return returnVal * mintSortOrder
    End Function
  End Class
End Class
```

Comment: SSS thanks for your example. How do I apply that to adding lines from a textbox to separate columns? I could also use a DGV as suggested but the problem remains how do I add lines from a textbox or richtextbox to LVW or DGV? dr.null's code example adds the lines to an array but how do I identify and separate the lines in the array and place one line in each column of the LVW or DGV? e.g. Line 1 > Column 1, Line 2 > Column 2, Line 3 > Column 3 until there are no more lines to add?

Answer (score 1):

dr.null's second answer as follows (from comments above) is the solution!

ah right. It's just

```
ListView5.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(TextBox42.Lines.Append(Now.ToString()).ToArray()))
```

Format the appended date as needed.

Comment: It seems to me you don't understand array syntax in VB. The `TextBox.Lines` property returns an array, so if you want just the first line, it is `TextBox42.Lines(0)`, second line is `TextBox42.Lines(1)` and so on (we start counting at zero). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/ for more info

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting your answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)